# In what logic are data being sent from a BMS device to an app?

Tags: java, android, byte

I develop an app on Android in Java that displays data from a [BMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_management_system) (battery management system).

I have to incorporate a client's logic in [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) into the app. C++ has JNI "hooks" prepared and Java calls byte[] from client's code which in turn works as a receiver for the BMS device. (It's a requirement.)

I read the communication protocol, but I'm still unsure how the data are logically sorted in byte[]. (Assuming the client's code doesn't modify data and keep the BMS generated byte[].)

What I don't understand is **whether data are send from the BMS as the following**

a) one batch of data includes multiple data identifiers and their data. To read it, I will iterate for a byte with an id and a byte with data next to the id.

`batch of data= (start frame|...| 70x (Data identification code | n. bytes of data)| ...|end of identity| checksum)`

or

b) byteArray consists of fully complete individual data units.  To read it, I have to identify units and then extract their single data.
Each unit starts and ends with all the "bloat" steps.
`unit = (start frame| ...|single Data identifier code | single data| ...|end of identity| checksum )`

`| unit_1  | unit_2 | unit_3 |... // 70x units in row`

Also, in either case, is there a specific order of identifiers to follow? I'm afraid when I iterate byte[] some data will == identifier, e.g., 0x79 which will lead to reading the wrong data, but if I know the order, I basically know their position.

**I tried:**

- read the communication protocol
- search stackoverflow.com
- search the Internet
- task it to the [Auto-GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-GPT) agent
- [ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT)
- [ChatPDF](https://easywithai.com/ai-writers/chatpdf/) to interpret the protocol

None of the sources gave me an answer and the AI also verified that based on the communication protocol, it's not possible to know.

My last hope is anyone who has experience with BMSs communication to explain this to me.

Bellow is my reader method that gets a value from C++ if needed and the relevant communication protocol parts.

This is my reader class *bmsReader.java* (I don't think it matters though):

```
...
public static native byte[] bmsBinnaryValue(int parBMSINDEX, int parJKINDEX);
...
```

### An example of communication:

| The serial numb er | The frame unit | The length of the byte |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STX | 2 | Start frame: 0x4E(78"N") 0x57(87"W") |
| ... | ... | .. | ... |
| 7 | Data identification code | 1 | Read individual data references (Table 5.1);Read all data and fill in 0x00 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 9 | End of identity | 1 | 0x68 |
| 10 | The checksum | 4 |  |

#### BMSreply

| The serial numb er | The frame unit | The length of the |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STX | 2 | Start frame: 0x4E(78"N") 0x57(87"W") |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 7 | Identifier on code | 1 | Write a single data reference (Table 5.1) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 9 | End of identity | 1 | 0X68 |
| 10 | The checksum | 4 |  |

#### 5.1 The BMS sets the data identification code

| Use instruction | Data identification code | The name of the | byte | type |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R | 0x79 | Single battery voltage | 3 *n | HEX | The first byte is the battery number, and the second is the voltage value mV. When reading all the data, 0 x 79 is followed by a byte length data, and then every three bytes in a group represents the electricity Pool voltage. |
| R | 0X83 | Total battery voltage | 2 | HEX | 0. 01 V 3500 * 0 . 01 = 35 . 0 0 v The minimum unit is 10 mV |

(The table includes approximately 70 identifiers, [here someone uses the same identifiers](https://github.com/jblance/mpp-solar/issues/256#issue-1360057027) if you need more ids, but their project is not directly related.)

The final goal is to show data in the Android app via a layout UI to the user, e.g., *battery voltage: 20V.0*, but I need to understand the logic behind reading the data to accomplish that.